# Hash function result and bucket number in unordered_set

Tags: c++, std, unordered-set

Suppose I have an `std::unordered_set<T> mySet` initialized with my own hash function `hashFunc(T item)`. What I want to do is first insert some items into `mySet`, and then have a function `search(T item)` that takes an item, finds which bucket `b` it would go if it were to be inserted **(but does not insert it)** and finally returns all other items on bucket `b`. Can I calculate `b` like this?

```
b = hashFunc(item)
```

Is it guaranteed that `b` is gonna be the bucket I'm looking for? If not, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: No, the hash-function calculates a hash not a bucket. And why do you need to find out which bucket an element might be in? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think getting the bucket might help you solve the problem? And doesn't the [normal bucket interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set#Bucket_interface) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bucket](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/bucket) method on `unordered_set` takes a key and returns the bucket index that an element with that key would go into. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<std::string> x = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};

  std::cout << "foo: " << x.bucket("foo") << "\n";
  std::cout << "fox: " << x.bucket("fox") << "\n";
  std::cout << "bat: " << x.bucket("bat") << "\n";
}
```

on my implementation, prints

```
foo: 2
fox: 0
bat: 1
```

Once you have the bucket index, you would then iterate over the items in that bucket by calling the [begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/begin2), [end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/end2) overloads that take a bucket index.

You shouldn't need to directly call your hash function.

Comment: The reference says `Returns the bucket number where the element with value k is located.` Your answer says it also acts like it said `would be located`. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Per the standard, it returns "the index of the bucket in which elements with keys equivalent to k would be found, if any such element existed" ([unord.req.general]).The element does not need to be in the set already.